# Словарь с разными типами значений

Tags: c#, .net

В общем, предположим задача получать данные из разных типов файлов: txt,access и т д.

Для этого я хочу сделать интерфейс:

```
interface IDataExtracotr<TOut>{
    TOut GetData(string pathToFile)
}
```

Далее я хочу создать класс на каждый тип и реализовать данный интерфейс. Понятное дело, что при чтении txt-файлов будет возвращаться строка, а при чтении Access-файла DataTable.

Далее, я хотел бы это запихать в словарь, что бы ключом было расширение файла, а значением обработчик.

Так вот, это у меня сделать не получиться из-за разных возвращаемых типов...

Можно ли как-то элегантно решить задачу? Можно рефлексией проверять возвращаемый тип и делать приведение, но это попахивает большим свичем...

Comment: А какой тип будет у ключа и значения того словаря? string и object?

Comment: @gil9red строка или перечисление. Не суть важно.

Answer (score 4):

К сожалению, мне кажется, без свича точно определить возвращаемый тип нельзя.

Я не знаю, для каких целей вам нужна именно такая архитектура, но более-менее допустимыми решениями можно считать следующие:

- Подумайте, нужно ли вам вообще возвращать какой-то тип. Если у вас подразумевается логика "пришёл неизвестный файл, я кладу его в ящик (интерфейс), а он уже сам знает что с ним делать", почему бы тогда и обработку полученных данных не делать в подобных DataExtractor'у классах, например `IDataHandler`, который использует `IDataExtractor`.
- Можно возвращать вместо конкретного типа абстрактный тип (например `Data`), а в классе `Data` уже сохранять информацию о том, как надо работать с данными. Короче, придумать обобщённый интерфейс. Но и тут без перебора вариантов `if`'ами или свичем не обойдётся.

UPD:
Совсем забыл, если вы планируете работать с этой структурой, заранее зная расширения файла, например вот так:

```cs
var textData = Extractors.Get(Extensions.TXT);
```

То советую пересмотреть Ваш вариант, возможно иная структура классов или иной метод получения нужного экстрактора подойдёт лучше. Вот например:

```cs
var extractor = new TextDataExtractor();
```

Comment: Первый вариант, наверное, более менее подходящий.